# Facing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intuit.karate.demo.util.SchemaUtils when trying to validate schema

Tags: testing, karate

I am trying to check the validate json schema using karate and I am facing this:

java.lang.RuntimeException: javascript evaluation failed: Java.type('com.intuit.karate.demo.util.SchemaUtils'), java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intuit.karate.demo.util.SchemaUtils

My pom dependencies are :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
        <version>${karate.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${karate.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.java-json-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

[Feature file syntax and json files locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usLey.png)

Can any one please suggest how to fix this ?

Comment: I think you are badly confused. read this section of the documentation carefully first: https://github.com/intuit/karate#schema-validation - if you still don't get it, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Actually I am trying to do a similar validation as mentioned in the first scenario o f  https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/schema/schema.feature

Comment: yes - which means you need to do advanced stuff such as java inter-op. I don't think you read the docs, karate actually does not recommend using json-schema validation and has a custom (superior) approach. anyway - if you are still stuck - look at the second link in my above comment - I have no other help to offer. all the best

Comment: If the json response is not very long then yes, its easy to use the schema validation offered by Karate. If the response is very long and complex I don't want to create the schema file manually and that when ready made validation, like other json schema validator can be helpful.

Comment: as I said, all the very best :) personally it is a waste of time - especially since the dev team would be generating code from the schema anyway - you are just over engineering. and then there's this: https://twitter.com/karatedsl/status/878984854012022784

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SchemaUtils is a class available in karate-demo which is not packed with karate-core,

so if you want to use the SchemaUtils copy that class and keep it inside you project and provide the correct package path for java interop

eg,

```
Java.type('<your new package>.SchemaUtils')
```

Answer (score 1):

please provide full stack trace information, as well as sourcecode.
Does you project even have this package "com.intuit.karate.demo.util.SchemaUtils" (don't know if it is included by default in the library)

Edit:

Bad coding habits aside: you can go script kiddy mode, grab the com.intuit.karate.demo.util.SchemaUtils -package from the demo real, and then you probably won't get your error anymore. As pointed out, you probably misunderstod how to use the library. You are probably calling functions from the tutorial / demo, which of course don't exist in your project.

Answer (score 1):

I removed this dependency, and all was working fine.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.22</version>
    </dependency>
```